# How to remove someone from Play Store Internal Testers

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

A user was part of the 'Internal Test' group for the app on Play Store. They are not an internal tester any more. I have removed them from the list. They have confirmed that they've gone and clicked on the 'Leave' link on the join testers page.

However, even now, whenever they try to purchase anything in the app, they only get the test-card payment options (always approves or always declines) with 5min renewal cycle.

How can a user be removed / leave the internal test group so they can make 'real' in-app purchases?

Comment: @soc Do you know anyone who could help with this? This appears to be related to user's test status not syncing between Google Play and, I'm guessing, the Google Pay service that presents the cards/purchase interface. The app clearly shows as being from production track. User is not in internal-test (but used to be). Yet, the payment interface shows testing payment methods, instead of real ones.

Comment: So to clarify, this for an Android Google Pay integration? If so, can you provide details on the request object sent to Google Pay `loadPaymentData` and the Google Pay environment that is being set for this user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to leave the test track you must uninstall and reinstall the app. I think it also says so on the Google Play store listing as soon as you leave the test track.

Edit:
You also need to Refund the test purchase. Go to Order management in Play console and do a refund.

Comment: Didn't work. Cleared data. Uninstalled app. Cleared play store cache. Installed app again, ensuring it wasn't any testing track. Still, the in app purchase only shows the internal test payment methods—test cards that always approve and always decline.

Comment: I've updated the comment. Forgot about the refund :)

Comment: Thanks again. That didn't work either. The user had never made a purchase using the test method.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I had missed a detail relating to purchase / license testing. There's a separate setting for selecting users who can use test purchase methods. This setting applies to all apps under a developer's account.

To add/remove users who can access test purchase methods, go to `Play Console » Settings » Developer Account » Account Details » License Testing`. Email addresses listed here are the ones who get presented with test payment methods, irrespective of which app release they are using (internal, alpha, beta or production).

Repeat: **Test purchase methods have no link to the app release/test track that the user is on**

Leaving this answer here because it solved my core query—*how to stop test purchase methods being presented to a user.*
WebFreak's answer above is correct for what I actually asked—*how to remove a user from a internal test track.*